# Can't send object of ComplexType to soap webservice from ksoap2 for android

Tags: android, web-services, soap, wsdl, ksoap2

I am doing a mobile application that by using ksoap2 uses web services.

So far i was able to send complex objects through the webservice that contained String, doubles, int, etc...

Then i was capable of send an array of bytes through the network. And now comes my problem:

When i try to create an object to send over the network when one of the parameters is an array of bytes i get a faultstring from the server.

The web-service i am accessing has the following wsdl file:

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:ns1="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd" xmlns:ns="http://sensors.components" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:ax21="http://sensors.components/xsd" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" targetNamespace="http://sensors.components">
<wsdl:types>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://sensors.components/xsd">
<xs:complexType name="Pic">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="accuracy" type="xs:double"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="imageInByte" nillable="true" type="xs:base64Binary"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="latitude" type="xs:double"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="longitude" type="xs:double"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="name" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="time" type="xs:long"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
<xs:schema xmlns:ax22="http://sensors.components/xsd" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://sensors.components">
<xs:import namespace="http://sensors.components/xsd"/>
<xs:element name="pictureWebservice">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="args0" nillable="true" type="ax21:Pic"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="pictureWebserviceResponse">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="pictureWebserviceRequest">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:pictureWebservice"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="pictureWebserviceResponse">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:pictureWebserviceResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="PictureWSPortType">
<wsdl:operation name="pictureWebservice">
<wsdl:input message="ns:pictureWebserviceRequest" wsaw:Action="urn:pictureWebservice"/>
<wsdl:output message="ns:pictureWebserviceResponse" wsaw:Action="urn:pictureWebserviceResponse"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="PictureWSSoap11Binding" type="ns:PictureWSPortType">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
<wsdl:operation name="pictureWebservice">
<soap:operation soapAction="urn:pictureWebservice" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:binding name="PictureWSSoap12Binding" type="ns:PictureWSPortType">
<soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
<wsdl:operation name="pictureWebservice">
<soap12:operation soapAction="urn:pictureWebservice" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:binding name="PictureWSHttpBinding" type="ns:PictureWSPortType">
<http:binding verb="POST"/>
<wsdl:operation name="pictureWebservice">
<http:operation location="pictureWebservice"/>
<wsdl:input>
<mime:content type="application/xml" part="parameters"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<mime:content type="application/xml" part="parameters"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="PictureWS">
<wsdl:port name="PictureWSHttpSoap11Endpoint" binding="ns:PictureWSSoap11Binding">
<soap:address location="http://accessible-serv.lasige.di.fc.ul.pt:8181/axis2/services/PictureWS.PictureWSHttpSoap11Endpoint/"/>
</wsdl:port>
<wsdl:port name="PictureWSHttpSoap12Endpoint" binding="ns:PictureWSSoap12Binding">
<soap12:address location="http://accessible-serv.lasige.di.fc.ul.pt:8181/axis2/services/PictureWS.PictureWSHttpSoap12Endpoint/"/>
</wsdl:port>
<wsdl:port name="PictureWSHttpEndpoint" binding="ns:PictureWSHttpBinding">
<http:address location="http://accessible-serv.lasige.di.fc.ul.pt:8181/axis2/services/PictureWS.PictureWSHttpEndpoint/"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

The object i am trying to send is as follows:

```
public class Pic implements KvmSerializable{

    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;
    private long time;
    private double accuracy;
    private String name;
    private byte[] imageInByte;

    public byte[] getImageInByte() {
        return imageInByte;
    }
    public void setImageInByte(byte[] imageInByte) {
        this.imageInByte = imageInByte;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }
    public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }
    public double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }
    public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }
    public double getAccuracy() {
        return accuracy;
    }
    public void setAccuracy(double accuracy) {
        this.accuracy = accuracy;
    }
    public long getTime() {
        return time;
    }
    public void setTime(long time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getProperty(int arg0) {
        switch(arg0){
        case 0:
            return latitude;
        case 1:
            return longitude;
        case 2:
            return time;
        case 3:
            return accuracy;
        case 4:
            return name;
        case 5:
            return imageInByte;
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public int getPropertyCount() {
        return 6;
    }
    @Override
    public void getPropertyInfo(int arg0, Hashtable arg1, PropertyInfo arg2) {
        switch(arg0){
        case 0:
            arg2.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            arg2.name = "latitude";
            break;
        case 1:
            arg2.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            arg2.name = "longitude";
            break;
        case 2:
            arg2.type = PropertyInfo.LONG_CLASS;
            arg2.name = "time";
            break;
        case 3:
            arg2.type = Double.class;
            arg2.name = "accuracy";
            break;
        case 4:
            arg2.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            arg2.name = "name";
            break;
        case 5:
            arg2.type = MarshalBase64.BYTE_ARRAY_CLASS;
            arg2.name = "imageInBytes";
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void setProperty(int arg0, Object arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(arg0){
        case 0:
            latitude = Double.parseDouble(arg1.toString());
            break;
        case 1:
            longitude = Double.parseDouble(arg1.toString());
            break;
        case 2:
            time = Long.parseLong(arg1.toString());
            break;
        case 3:
            accuracy = Double.parseDouble(arg1.toString());
            break;
        case 4:
            name = arg1.toString();
            break;
        case 5:
            imageInByte = (byte[])arg1;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
```

The values i am using to access the web service are the following:

namespace = "http://sensors.components"
url = "http://accessible-serv.lasige.di.fc.ul.pt:8181/axis2/services/PictureWS?wsdl"
soap action = "http://sensors.components/pictureWebservice"
method name = "pictureWebservice"

Then the code i am using to send it over to the webservice is the following:

```
String NAMESPACE = "http://sensors.components/xsd";
        try {
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(connection.getNAMESPACE(), connection.getMETHOD_NAME());

            PropertyInfo object = new PropertyInfo();
            object.setName("picture");
            object.setValue(picture);
            object.setType(picture.getClass());
            object.setNamespace(NAMESPACE);
            request.addProperty(object);

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            MarshalDouble md = new MarshalDouble();
            md.register(envelope);
            new MarshalBase64().register(envelope);


            envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "Pic", new Pic().getClass());

            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(
                    connection.getURL());

            androidHttpTransport.call(connection.getSOAP_ACTION(), envelope);

            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
            System.out.println("response: " + response.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Although i have tried and succeed to pass objects before with doubles and registering them and being able to pass byte[] i am not being able to pass a complex type with a byte[] inside it as an argument.

The logcat error is presented next:

```
SoapFault - faultcode: 'soapenv:Server' faultstring: 'Exception occurred while trying to invoke service method pictureWebservice' faultactor: 'null' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@4153d588
12-13 22:26:51.363: W/System.err(5393):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.parseBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:112)
12-13 22:26:51.363: W/System.err(5393):     at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:137)
12-13 22:26:51.363: W/System.err(5393):     at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:63)
12-13 22:26:51.363: W/System.err(5393):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:100)
12-13 22:26:51.363: W/System.err(5393):     at memory.aid.webservices.WSClient.WSClientPictureFile(WSClient.java:92)
12-13 22:26:51.363: W/System.err(5393):     at memory.aid.memoryaid.MemoryAid$1.run(MemoryAid.java:185)
12-13 22:26:51.363: W/System.err(5393):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
12-13 22:26:51.367: W/System.err(5393):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-13 22:26:51.367: W/System.err(5393):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-13 22:26:51.367: W/System.err(5393):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
12-13 22:26:51.367: W/System.err(5393):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-13 22:26:51.367: W/System.err(5393):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-13 22:26:51.375: W/System.err(5393):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
12-13 22:26:51.375: W/System.err(5393):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-13 22:26:51.375: W/System.err(5393):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Anyone has any ideas, solutions or suggestions? thank you very much in advance.

EDIT:

from what i can tell the problem is that somehow in the server's webservice i am calling imageInByte parameter in the class Pic is null. No other parameter is null. Name, latitude, longitude, accuracy and time are all valid parameters byt imageInByte is null. Why? pls help

Comment: What is happening is that in the server at the web-service the parameter for Pic imageInByte is null. No other parameter is null only imageInByte. Why? can anyone help me? no responses so far.

Answer (score 0):

In your wsdl, you have defined this field "imageInByte" as simple type, thats why it is giving u this error.

Define it as complex type, having all fields you are trying to pass.

Thanks,
ambuj